# JSF (Primefaces) Не получается заполнить SelectOneListBox

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Пробую заполнить элемент значениями из ArrayList.

```
<p:panel id="puserList" header="Список пользователей" style="margin:10px; text-align: center; width:20%;">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="10">              
           <p:selectOneListbox id="userList" value="#{adminS.selectedUser}" var="t">
            <f:selectItem value="#{adminS.userList}" var="user" itemLabel="#{user.fullName}" itemValue="#{user}" />
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{t.fullName}" />
            </p:column>            
        </p:selectOneListbox>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
```

В Бине

```
@ManagedBean(name="adminS", eager = true)
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class AdminService {

        private List<User> userList;
        private User user;
        private String selectedUser;

        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {                        
            userList = getUsersFromDB();

        }   
}

// getters setters
```

Уже испробовал все комбинации, страница не грузится с ошибкой java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to javax.faces.model.SelectItem.

Comment: `f:selectItems` для лучшей наглядности (и только наглядности, на самом деле s не должна быть большой) выделяю `f:selectItemS`

Comment: Да, спасибо, не заметил.  Помогло.  Теперь ошибок нет, только элемент, почему-то, не заполняется. Буду копать дальше.